# Diseño problemático debido a clases estáticas, no estáticas y serialización

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio

Estoy realizando un programa que consiste básicamente en un formulario hecho con **Visual en C#**. Es una *Base de Datos* que almacena una lista de objetos de tipo `Libro`. Mi problema surge cuando quiero escribir y leer la `List` a un *fichero*, porque se produce, pero salen errores que no se de dónde vienen.

Lo mejor es que veáis un poco mi código para entender mi problemilla.

Código inicial:

```
namespace WindowsFormsApp1{

    public class Libro{
        [Serializable]
        public class Book{
            public string Nombre { get; set; }
            public string Autor { get; set; }
            public string Editorial { get; set; }

            public Book (string nombre, string autor, string editorial){
                this.Nombre = nombre;
                this.Autor = autor;
                this.Editorial = editorial;
            }
        }    

    public static List<Book> biblioteca = ReadFromBinaryFile<List<Book>>("biblioteca.txt");

    public static void WriteToBinaryFile<T>(string filePath, T objectToWrite, bool append = false){
        using (Stream stream = File.Open(filePath, append ? FileMode.Append : FileMode.Create)){
            var binaryFormatter = new System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter();
            binaryFormatter.Serialize(stream, objectToWrite);
        }
    }

    public static T ReadFromBinaryFile<T>(string filePath){
        using (Stream stream = File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Open)){
            var binaryFormatter = new System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter();
            return (T)binaryFormatter.Deserialize(stream);
        }
    }
}
```

}

En otro formulario tengo varios campos en los que el usuario escribe titulo, autor etc del libro, y pulsando un botón se añade a mi `List`.

```
private void insertarbutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
    Libro.Book nuevo = new Libro.Book(textBoxtituloinsertar.Text, textBoxautorinsertar.Text, textBoxeditorialinsertar.Text);
    Libro.biblioteca.Add(nuevo);
    MessageBox.Show("Libro insertado correctamente", "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
    textBoxtituloinsertar.Text = "";
    textBoxautorinsertar.Text = "";
    textBoxeditorialinsertar.Text = "";
    this.Close();
}
```

Tengo programado que cuando el usuario clickea en el botón de salir del programa, mi `List` se serialice y escriba en un fichero, sin embargo me encuentro con este problema:

```
private void close_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
    Libro.WriteToBinaryFile<List<Libro.Book>>("biblioteca.txt", Libro.biblioteca);
    Application.Exit();
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sin embargo lo que es curioso y no me explico es que a pesar de esos errores de compilación, los datos se guardan en el fichero, y cuando reinicio el programa, se leen correctamente y están guardados. Pude verlos en un datagrid que me fabriqué para ver qué contenía mi `List`

```
this.dataGridView1.DataSource = Libro.biblioteca;
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entonces mis preguntas son: ¿por qué aunque he leído en todos lados que no se puede serializar "cosas" static, la serialización se produce y hay una escritura de datos? ¿los errores que me salen, exactamente de qué son? porque no me indica la línea concreta de código...

Agradezco cualquier respuesta, llevo horas buscando la clave pero no logro ver el fallo.

Comment: no estas serializando una clase estatica... estas serializando un objeto estatico, que es distinto... Igual ahi arriba hay codigo que no se donde deberia estar.. y por favor, evita los comentarios como el que hiciste al principio. Si un "iluminado" piensa que el problema esta alli, casi seguro que esta alli. Las preguntas se leen completas antes de declararlas duplicadas, y tienen que ser validadas por 5 "iluminados". Evita ese tipo de comentarios.

Comment: @gbianchi pues no se que decirte, hace un tiempo subí una pregunta y como a los 10 segundos de postearla me la marcaron como duplicada (y pregunté otra cosa que la que aparecía en el enlace que dejaron como solución duplicada). Dudo que en menos de 30 segundos un tío marque como duplicada la pregunta y dé la casualidad de que 4 más lo hagan en el mismo momento. Quizá tuve mala suerte.

Comment: no puedo llegar a la parte de guardar en el archivo porque me manda muchos errores antes, quizás estas en modo release y con try catch por eso no te muestra los errores pero yo intentando usar el código que mostraste no pude guardar en archivo ni siquiera hacerle un parse. Me podrías indicar el formato del texto del archivo "biblioteca.txt"